# How to insert data into DB from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Consider:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Elibrary_management2
{
    public partial class user_registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Signup button click
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Response.Write("<script>alert('successfull')</script>");
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                string sqlquary = ("insert into member_master_tbl(full_name,dob,contact_no,email,state,city,pincode,full_address,member_id,password,account_status) values(@full_name,dob,@contact_no,@email,@state,@city,@pincode,@full_address,@member_id,@password,@account_status");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquary, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_no", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox6.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincode", TextBox7.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_address", TextBox8.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member_id", TextBox9.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending");

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Signup Successfull');</script>");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Msg 2809, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 
> The request for procedure 'member_master_tbl' failed because 'member_master_tbl' is a table object.

What is the problem?

Comment: Seems command type property is missing in the SqlCommand. Please add `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` and try again

Comment: No well-written question should relate to both a `TextBox` and data access. If you're inserting text into a database then you're using a `string`. Where that `string` comes from is irrelevant to the data access.

Comment: Is this the code that actually threw the exception? Or is this *modified* code that tries to "simplify" the question? Why is the query string surrounded by parentheses? Did the *real* code try to use just the table name? Or is there a stored procedure containing the `INSERT` ?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: @SelvaS, `Text` is the default value for `CommandType` and there's nothing in this code that sets it to `StoredProcedure`.

Comment: You are missing an `@` prefix on your `dob` parameter. I'm not sure whether that would cause this specific error message but it's a problem regardless.

Comment: Also, regarding the same parameter, it is VERY BAD that you are providing a `string` from a date column. You should be validating the input and converting it yourself. You should also be using `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` and specifying the correct data type, as suggested.

Comment: The code has several issues, from leaking connections to storing unencrypted passwords to `AddWithValue` to the `_tbl` suffix, to storing dates as strings. I wouldn't be surprised if the code that actually threw the error is different from the current one. ADO.NET, SQL and the documentation tutorials work. There's no need for experimentation. Instead of trying to get a query to work by trial and error, create a simple Console application that just opens a connection and inserts a row. It's a *LOT* easier to fix just one thing at a time. And *do* follow an ADO.NET tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors are for *several* reasons.

Firstly, you have

```
member_master_tbl(
```

Well, you have a table name with "(" in it - it going to confuse SQL.

(Do you *really* have a table named above?)

So, place a space after the table name

Next up: don't *ever* let code spread off the screen like that. You can't see, nor look at the SQL. It becomes like coding in a dark room with a blindfold on. You can't see your code, and as result, you're just now guessing and hacking to make this work.

The fact of surrounding the string with "(" shows that you just guessing now.

The connection will always have been closed. Since it always been closed by your *correct previous* working code, then you *never* will have to test or check your connection object, right? In other words, work on the assumption that your previous code was good, and correct, and since one makes that assumption, then you never have to close the connection!

And since your previous code is assumed to be correct, then you never have to check if the connection is open either!

And how do you *always* make sure you don't have that stray connection?

Answer: you let the *system* take care of this, and it will *always* have closed and cleaned up and disposed the connection for you, that's how!

And how do you do the above? You adopt using blocks. It will actually *save* you writing code!

Worse yet, since your SQL statement runs off the edge of the screen: note how your missing the closing ")" for your *VALUES* list.

but then again, you can't see or notice this, right!

Remember, good developers are not really that good.

But, what they do really fantastically? **They write code that humans can read easy, so *then* seeing errors is also** ***easy!***

In other words, good developers are actually better at writing code that easy to see and fix, not that they have super brains that see errors!

Next up:

*Strong* type your parameters. That means if a value is "int", then tell the system that the value supposed to be int, etc.

So, let's fix the table name, since your table name is *not* "member_master_tbl("

Without a space, you seeing a error message that this looks like a function!

```
eg:    abc(
```

Wrap your SQL connection block in using statements. This means you can leave work early, make happy hour and have time to get lucky. It also means the connection will be closed for you, disposed for you, and you don't care, or nor have to worry about it (again, makes things easy).

You find that good coders are not better at coding, but they learned to avoid code that hard to read, and hard to fix. The result is such code is child's play, since it was easer to write, read, fix.

So, I would suggest this code as a start:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
{
    string sqlquary =
        @"insert into member_master_tbl
        (
            full_name, dob, contact_no, email, state, city, pincode,
            full_address, member_id, password, account_status
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @full_name, dob, @contact_no, @email, @state, @city, @pincode,
            @full_address, @member_id, @password, @account_status
        )";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquary, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@full_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@contact_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pincode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox7.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@full_address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@member_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox9.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@account_status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "pending";

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
Response.Write("<script>alert('Signup Successfull');</script>");
```

Even if the above code has some errors, it going to be far more easy to change, fix, and read. However, *strong* type the parameter's as above shows, and edit + fix the above to MATCH the data types in the table.

And those name for text boxes? Really, don't use TextBox1 unless there is *only* 1 or 2 text boxes on the webform. Beyond 1 or 2 text boxes on the page: then *always* give each text box a nice readable id of what it means.

So, how would I have written the above code?

My version looks like this:

```
       int PK = General.FwriterAdd(EditArea, "member_master_tbl")
```

EditArea in above is a div. Since after one day of hand coding the sending or loading of controls on a page? It is way too much work!

So, I wrote *one* general routine that takes the controls, and sends them to the database for me, and now for every page with a bunch of controls, I don't have to write the same thing over and over, and I have *one* routine that works for all web pages. But, let's leave how that code works for another day and time.